# How to print Date

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have two Pages used for printing.

1) PagePrinting.xaml 
2) FormattedPage.xaml

in PagePrinting.xaml , I used the code below to reference the FormattedPage.xaml

FrameworkElement page1;
 page1 = new FormattedPage(); 
 CanvasPrintContainer.Children.Add(page1);

The problem:

- The txtBlkDatePrint is blank when it is shown in PagePrinting.xaml

What I need to do?

```
in CodeBehind of FormattedPage.xaml :

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            txtBlkDatePrint.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("d");
        }

FormattedPage.xaml:

< StackPanel x:Name="header" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Height="60">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
           <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
         <Paragraph>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlkDatePrint" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="28" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="204"/>
        </Paragraph>
          </RichTextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `Paragraph` takes in a collection of `Block`s as `Content`, of which `TextBlock` ironically is not. Try instead using a `Run`.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="header" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Height="60">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <RichTextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
            <Paragraph>
                <Run x:Name="txtBlkDatePrint" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="28" Text=""/>
            </Paragraph>
         </RichTextBlock>
     </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Though, if you just want to display simple text, you may not need the `RichTextBlock` at all.

Comment: Wait, I think I just noticed that you're adding the page as a child. That's not navigating to it, so `OnNavigatedTo` won't be called.

Comment: Found the solution by passing data to the constructor as OnNavigatedTo will never be executed. Thanks